# How important is being in a good institute for a theoretical physicist?

Tags: research-process, funding, physics, interpersonal-issues, independent-researcher

Will being in a underfunded institute and with mediocre colleagues hinder the performance of a theoretical physicist to a great degree?

Comment: given enough exposure, doesn't everybody think everybody nearby is mediocre?

Comment: @davyjones Given your question, have you ever worked with *really great* people?

Comment: Si tacuisses, philosophus mansisses ...

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, Aye Aye Captain, of course I'm exaggerating. I've seen *really great* people work, yet those people never say anything about their colleagues being mediocre.

Comment: @davyjones I now see belatedly that I missed the sarcasm in your first statement, fair enough...

Comment: You need two things, I think. One is a good advisor and the other is enough funding or other infrastructure to support your research. With that, and hard work, you can be successful.

Comment: I don't see why mediocre word seems to have offended anyone here. Is it wrong to say that all people in scientific community are not equally talented? Isn't it also true that there is vast difference in productivity of researchers from institutes elite and institutes and bad institutes? BTW I'm a graduate student.

Comment: I don't know which place you come from, but you must be very lucky if my assumptions are wrong. Unfortunately I'm not from such a place I suppose. I'm from india and in our country, about 95% of people academia are in there because they couldn't get any other job. They'd can't be less interested in teaching or learning. Even the term mediocre is a euphemism for such people.

Comment: I don't want to put them in the same bag as the other few great people and disrespect the later. Those are the people who dedicate their lives for research. It'd be a sacrilege to call them all equal. My question is if It's getting difficult for me to make it to any of the good institutes with actual researchers, should I consider the other mediocre institutions?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

A good student who is very self motivated can rise above. That means you would need to be doing a lot of work in addition to the work assigned in class. If you can do that, consistently for your entire degree, you can come out knowing as much as you would in a "tough" school.

It's a two-fold challenge.

First, there is doing it and keeping it up without somebody to drive you.  If you are that sort of person then GREAT! More power to you, I wish you well. But you won't need my good wishes, you will be too busy creating your own good future.

Second, there is getting recognition for this extra work. Eventually you will want to do something after undergrad. Whether that's grad school or industry or whatever, you need an entrance that allows you to get some credit for the extra work.

Sometimes, a possible solution to the second part is to publish something in a research journal. Lots of undergrads publish a research article. Of course, it's a small fraction of undergrads overall. But if you can publish something it will go a long way to helping you in whatever your plans are for after undergrad.

Sometimes it's extra-curricular projects. Are you technologically gifted? Build something keen. Are you software creative? Write an interesting and useful computer program. Are you the gifted writer? Write a web site that explains some interesting physics topic. Are you a good video presenter? Maybe something for the Khan academy.

https://www.khanacademy.org/

If you are fortunate in the "summer jobs" you get, that can be very helpful also. One of the undergrads I met at a "cow college" was doing some interesting work with a local research company. They were doing a thing with testing microwaves for therapy in sports medicine. He got to do some of the mundane measurement work. It looked good on his resume, it taught him a lot about microwaves, and it paid the bills.

Sometimes a nearby school will have enrichment opportunities. If you were at a small school in Southern Ontario, you could consider managing to get some time at McMaster University.  They have a pool type nuclear reactor. You could get training on that for a few months. That would look pretty good on your resume for certain jobs and grad schools. Many universities will have some kind of lab or facility that you can do some kind of exchange program.

From the other side of things, a gifted student in a "tough" school may not achieve maximum results. Tough schools can sometimes be very regimented and by-the-regulation-book. "My way or the highway" kind of thing. It does not always nurture the creativity of a young student who has just come from a high school where he was top-of-the-pops while hardly trying. And tough schools might not have a friendly environment. Students might be far more competitive minded, angling for scholarships and such.

The right school for you is a difficult choice. And it's one that, once made, is difficult to unmake.